Using std::enable_if to avoid ambiguous templated binary operator overloading
I want to use std::enable_if to avoid ambiguous overloaded operator*(T,U) (or redefinitions) from MyClass*otherT vs otherT*MyClass vs MyClassT*MyClassT.
Let's say MyClass declaration is:
template <typename T> class MyClassT { ... };

Then in global scope:
template <typename T, typename U>
MyClassT<T> operator*(const MyClassT<T>& t, const MyClassT<U>& u)
{
    //...
}

template <typename T, typename U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<MyClassT<T>, U>,bool> = true >
MyClassT<T> operator*(const MyClassT<T>& t, const U& u)
{
    //...
}

template <typename T, typename U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<MyClassT<U>, T>,bool> = true >
MyClassT<U> operator*(const T& t, const MyClassT<U>& u)
{
    //...
}

But, this code still can't find the overloaded operator for it:
MyClassT<double> a;
double b;
MyClassT<double> c = a * b; 

I need help, what's wrong?

Always post complete error along with your question with a [mcve]

... is not valid c++. Post real code only. I've seen people(askers) change their question after an answer has been posted saying that was just an example but not the real code. So always post real code. That edit then invalidates the already posted answers.

@user12002570 its just an example of code snippet, and the body of the function is not relevant for the question

@wohlstad the second one should with T=double, and U=double the MyClassT<double> is not the same as  double , so declaration would valid (notice !std::is_same_v

@uray You don't need to use enable_if here at all. See my answer below.

Add more examples to your question. You seem to be changing the requirements of the question after two answer have already been posted.

a moment,  I will back to it, the answer below is work on the test, but my case (with complete code) its not working, I will check if there is something I missed on the simplified code that not represent the question

okay guys sorry, it seems i have problem that I have AnotherMyClassT<T> that also overload the operator* between the AnotherMyClassT<T> and U so somehow there is multiple / conflicting overload between MyClassT and AnotherMyClassT

@uray you are right about the second overload. Which means that your posted code actually has no problem (the demo in a comment under the accepted answer shows that it compiles)

@uray You might want to edit your question to say that you want to improve your question by making it more readable as your posted code already works.

You don't need to use enable_if and  default argument here as shown below.
template <typename T, typename U >
MyClassT<T> operator*(const MyClassT<T>& t, const U& u)
{
    //...
    return {};
}

template <typename T, typename U >
MyClassT<U> operator*(const T& t, const MyClassT<U>& u)
{
    //...
    return {};
} 
MyClassT<double> a;
double b;
MyClassT<double> c = a * b;  //works now
MyClassT<double> k = b * a; //works  

Working demo

try with int b

@uray this is why we ask for a [mre] you should show all the code that you want to work otherwise people will make assumptions

@user12002570 following the comments under the question - can you explain why the second overload (with T=double, and U=double) does not fit the case of c = a * b in the OP's code ? (despite the usage of !std::is_same_v<MyClassT<T>, U>).

@wohlstad It does work actually. See demo

Oh... I see. So this means the whole question was actually wrong, isn't it ? (I mean in the sense that the original code was actually working)

@wohlstad Yup, they missed to write bool. But still they don't need the sfinae here.

;@wohlstad Yes, originally it didn't compile.
